# How to make a scroll content in between the header and footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css, overflow

```html
<div class="flex h-screen w-full flex-col">
  <header class="h-64 bg-cyan-300">
    <h1>I'm header</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="pageContent" class="flex flex-1 flex-col overflow-auto bg-green-400">
    <div id="content" class="h-[calc(100%-50px)] overflow-auto">
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
      <h1 class="h-32">test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pagination" class="flex h-[50px] w-full items-center justify-center bg-purple-300">Pagination</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/

I need `pageContent` to be scrollable, not sure if this is right.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pyaH.png)

The above code is worked as expected, my problem is the second overflow-auto is added but why there is no second scrollbar y-axis.

Is there a more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what achieves it:

```
<div class="flex flex-col w-full h-screen">
  <header class="grow-0">
    header
  </header>
  <main class="grow-1 overflow-y-auto">
    content
  </main>
  <footer class="grow-0">
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Or, in plain CSS:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.flex-layout {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-layout > * {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.flex-layout main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-layout">
  <header>header</header>
  <main>
    content
    <!--
      <div style="min-height: 200vh"></div>
    !-->
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

It can also be achieved with `display: grid` on container, using the same logic.

What's valuable about this solution is that it allows content to overflow without having to hard-code heights on either child of container. Header and footer can vary in height and the content adjusts.

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/W3bpmywdy1).

---

Notes:

- footer has to be taken out of content (so the container has 3 children: header, content and footer)
- this works with what is called a "hard" height (something that's actually translated into hard units, not percentage) on container or one of its parents.
  For example, if you wanted this to take the full height of a parent element - and give it `height: 100%`, it would only work if one element in the chain of parents had a "hard" height (in `px`, `em`, `vh`, etc...). Without it, the `overflow-y: auto` has no effect, as there's no set height at which the overflow would start.
- special care should be taken on short viewports, to avoid accessibility problems. If the sum of heights of header and footer is equal or bigger than the container height, the content will no longer be accessible. To make sure it's always accessible, you might want to wrap everything in a `@media (min-height: Npx)` (in tailwind you'd need to hard-code a min height on container (or on content) `min-h-[Npx]`, where `Npx` is the container height at which you'd rather prefer the pagination to go out of the container than to shrink the content further). To avoid double scrollbars you might want to move the `overflow-y` from content to container in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Make your header and pagination `position: fixed` and `width: 100%`.
For header add `top: 0`.
For pagination add `bottom: 0`.